# How to publish many apps on the base of one

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have client android application that works with different basic links. And it should be different apps with different packages. But the way it will handle requests\responses is the same. I need to change one line with link in the code, but leave all the code base. How can I do this?

I know the library way, but it doesn't suits to me. Also I heard something about different flavors.

Comment: One more problem is that I use androidannotations and the apt plugin doesn't support multiple flavors =\

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with different flavors for single app(need to setup gradle file for flavors in your project.
With different flavor you can define different string files and source code(System will get the file from different folder according to flavor.).
Check out developer guild http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Answer (score 0):

gradle product flavors is what you're looking for

```
 productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
    }
    free {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.free"
    }
 }
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

define different productFlavors and you can add different strings.xml file's for each of them. During build the right one will be put to you apk file.

Answer (score 0):

If You use Android Studio or another gradle builder You can use productt flavour.

In build.gradle You have To define something like that:

```
productFlavors {
        Flav2{
            applicationId = "com.example.flav1"
        }

        Flav1{
            applicationId = "com.example.flav2"
        }
    }
```

Then you have to create a class with your const. For example

```
package com.example.const;
public class Blabla
{
  public static final String LINK="";
}
```

Then for each of your flavour inside src folder You have to create directory with the name of each flavour.

Inside of each Flav folder you have to put file you want to replace in different flavours (ex. out Blabla class).

So finnaly you should get something like that

```
src/main/java/
stc/Flav1/java/com/example/const/Blabla.java
src/Flav2/java/com/example/const/Blabla.java
```

Each of Blabla class should have their specific links inside.

Inside your 'regular' project You can use that class simply with

```
import com.example.cont.Blabla;
```

and use const specific for current flavour you want

Then you can build specific flavour with

`grable clean assembleRelaseFlav1`

Maybe a little chaotic answer but If you have more questions feel free to ask :)